# Class template refers to itself in type-constraint expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

I'm trying to implement [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) with C++20 concept. The key is to prevent the parent class template from being instantiated by any type argument except its subclass.

Compiler complains about the self-referencing `CRTP_Root` in the `requires-clause`:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

//error: ‘CRTP_Root’ was not declared in this scope
//     | requires std::derived_from<derived_type, CRTP_Root<derived_type>>

template<typename derived_type>
requires std::derived_from<derived_type, CRTP_Root<derived_type>>
class CRTP_Root {

};

class CRTP_child : public CRTP_Root<CRTP_child> {

};
```

Since `requires-clause` must be part of the declaration, there seems no way to write a forward declaration of such self-referring constrained class template. Is there any workaround?

Comment: No workaround for the requires-clause, but you can put the check in a static_assert **inside** the constructor. At that point the class is fully defined.

Comment: You could self-refered in constraints, but can't check the inheritance relationship since the derived class is incomplete yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to prevent the parent class template from being instantiated by any type argument except its subclass. one possible solution might be making the `CRTP_Root`'s ctor private, and use `friend` to decorate `derived_type`

```cpp
template<typename derived_type>
class CRTP_Root {
public:
  // polymorphic interfaces
private:
  CRTP_Root() {}
  friend derived_type;
};

class CRTP_child : public CRTP_Root<CRTP_child> {

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CRTP to refer to yourself in the constraints.

```cpp
template<typename derived_type, template <typename> typename tml_base>
requires std::derived_from<derived_type, tml_base<derived_type>>
struct CRTP_Helper {};

template<typename derived_type>
class CRTP_Root : CRTP_Helper<derived_type, CRTP_Root> {};
```

The problem here is you can't check it because the derived class is incomplete at that time.

See the error message in [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5Kd7YbYbf).